# $(X_n)_{n}$ monotone and $X_n \to X$ converge in probability => $X_n \to X$ almost surely

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X,X_1,X_2,...$ be random variables, such that $(X_n)_{n}$ is monotone and $X_n \to X$ converge in probability. I saw the following proof for $X_n \to X$ almost surely:

There exists $(n_j)_j \subset \mathbb N$ such that $(X_n)_{j}(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ as $j \to \infty$  for almost all $\omega$.

Since $X_n$ is monotone, for all of these $\omega$, we have that $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$. This is because, if $|(X_n)_{j}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon$ for all $j \ge j_0$, then we also have 
$|(X_n)(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge n_{j_0}$.

I have to admit that I don't quite see how this follows from the monotonicity:

Let $X_l(\omega) \le X_m(\omega) \le X_{l+1}(\omega)$ or $X_l(\omega) \ge X_m(\omega) \ge X_{l+1}(\omega)$ with $l, l+1 \in (n_j)_j$, $m \in \mathbb N$ and $l \le m \le l+1$. Does this already imply, that $|X_l(\omega) - X(\omega)|  \ge |X_m(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge |X_{l+1}(\omega) - X(\omega)|$? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A monotone sequence always has a limit, but that limit could be $\pm\infty$. If $x_n\to a\in[-\infty,+\infty]$, then $x_{n_j}\to a$ for any subsequence $\{n_j\}$. You have shown that for a particular subsequence $\{n_j\}$, $X_{n_j}(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ for almost every $\omega$. Since $X(\omega)\neq\pm\infty$, what can you conclude?

Comment: $X_n(\omega)$ is convergent for almost every $\omega$?

Comment: Yes, and moreover the limit is $X(\omega)$.